# Avoiding duplication of key/data

Tags: javascript

I have a design annoyance with some existing code in JS. The code is working, so I have no desperate hurry to change it, but the duplication shown below does annoy me. What is the usual/recommended/official way of avoiding this situation?

The actual system is a large/complex financial system, so I have simplified it to the most basic example which demonstrates the problem:

```
var colours={
     red:{id:"red", vals:[1,0,0]},
       green:{id:"green", vals:[0,1,0]},
       grey:{id:"grey", vals:[0.5,0.5,0.5]}
 // ...etc
    };

// id needs to be known internally within the object - thus it is defined as a property.
// e.g:
colour.prototype.identify(console.log(this.id));

// id also needs to be used externally to find an object quickly.
// e.g:
function getcolour(s){return colours[s];}

// Although this works. It does mean duplicating data, with the theoretical possibility of a mismatch:
var colours={//...
      blue:{id:"green", // oh dear...
```

How would this normally be handled by the experts?

Comment: Take a look to [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is somewhat subjective.

When creating my applications I typically try do do the following:

- never define same data in multiple places. source should always be unambiguous
- if I need to create any indices for faster/easier access, I use utility methods to do it. Those methods should be properly unit-tested, so that I would have little doubts on them doing the wrong thing
- use third party libraries as much as possible (such as already suggested lodash or underscore) to minimize the amount of code to be written/maintained.

If your algorithms and utilities are properly unit-tested you should not worry (too much) about getting the data into inconsistent state. However, if those are critically important systems/interfaces, you may add some validation on output. And it is generally a good practice to have data validation and marshaling on input.

Explanation on the utility methods:
 if you have data array, say

```
var data = [{"id":"i_1", ...}, {"id":"i_2", ...},{"id":"i_3",....}];
```

Then and you have to create an index out of that or create more data sets based on the original array, then you create yourself a library of utility methods that do the modification on the array, create derivative data sets, or iterate on the array and create a resulting item on the fly. For example:

```
var createIndex = function( arr ){
    // do something that converts the data array with expected structure to object
    // { 
    //     i_1: {"id":"i_1", ...},
    //     i_2: {"id":"i_2", ...},
    //     i_3: {"id":"i_3", ...}
    return newObj;
}
```

This method will create a hash-map to access your data, which is faster then to iterate over the original array all the time. But now, this method you can easily unit-test and be sure that when you use it on the source data to get your intended dataset, there will be no inconsistency.

Comment: Agreed on point 1 - that's the whole reason I asked the question.

Can you elaborate on how a 'utility method' is going to grant faster access than colours[s]. I do not follow your train of thought.

Comment: @Richard added clarification to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change the colours[key] direct access with other method to avoid duplication.
Any other attempt will lead to processing and you have mentioned that you have a large amount of data.

I assume that the duplication is over the incoming data that is a waste.
An example of processing over the network data consuming could be, going over the map object and set the id dynamically according to the key. (processing vs traffic)

```
colours[key].id = key
```

Comment: Forgive me if the question was not clear enough. There are no duplicate objects - the code works fine. The duplication is the face that the key is stored twice and so could (theoretically) be inconsistent.

There is no actual bug to be fixed - I was simply looking for tips on avoiding such an inelegant design.

Comment: That I understood, but does the data is coming from the server like you described? If so I tried to explain why sometimes you want to stick to a solutions like yours and not change it since other solutions like someone gave in here will be a processing that will take time especially when it involved big data. The example I gave you will add processing and remove some unnecessary duplicate data that you can process in the client - duplicate I refer to green:{vals:[0,1,0]} instead of  green:{id:"green", vals:[0,1,0]} smaller data traffic

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your object converting it to an array of objects and then filtering unique values. Converting it to an array would allow you to perform a lot of operations quicker and easier.

So you can map your object to an array:

```
var coloursArray = myObj.map(function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

Remove duplicates:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    return coloursArray.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[id]).indexOf(obj[id]) === pos;
    });
}
```

You can remove duplicates from an array using for example underscore.js through the `.uniq method`:

```
var uniqueColoursArray = _.uniq(coloursArray , function(c){ return c.id; });
```

Moreover, this function is pretty useless because you can access your element directly:

```
function getcolour(s){return colours[s];}
```

Calling `colours[s]` it is also shorter than `getcolour(s)`. Your function would make sense if you pass also the array because it is not accessible in some other scope.

Then I can't understand why you do pass a console.log as parameter here:

```
colour.prototype.identify(console.log(this.id));
```

maybe you would like to pass just the `this.id`

Comment: I fear that I have not explained the problem clearly enough.  
I am not trying to remove duplicate elements from an array. I am concerned that the datum (id) is duplicated by being stored in two separate places: as the key in the enclosing object and as a property of the child object.  
I was simply wondering if there was a clever design method which I had overlooked which would avoid this.

Comment: yeah it was not clear. Just change your design in this way:
`var colours=[
     {id:"red", vals:[1,0,0]},
     {id:"green", vals:[0,1,0]},
     {id:"grey", vals:[0.5,0.5,0.5]}
];`